# Keyword Metadata not supported for entitymodel and sql server

Tags: sql-server, winforms

I'm currently trying to define a dynamic SQL Connection where I get the Password from the resources. While doing so though I get a "Keyword metadata not supported" error.

My Connection is:

```
Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "metadata = res://*/ku_General_EntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/ku_General_EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/ku_General_EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MySqlServer;initial catalog=SBAllgemein;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;Password=XXReplacementPassWordXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;".Replace("XXReplacementPassWordXX", Properties.Resources.SQLServerPassword);
```

As sated in a similar Problem I've tried to replace the data Provider System.Data.SqlClient  with an EntityClient instead but to no avail.

My question is what can I do here?

Comment: Connection string usually starts with "Data Source.. " Do you get your string from web.config file?

Comment: nope I got it directly from the app.config  (as ist a winforms applicaiton using a sub-dll Project it has no web.config file).

Comment: I don't know what you mean "directly" - do you copy and paste it manually? If so, try 
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "data source=MySqlServer;initial catalog=SBAllgemein;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;Password=XXReplacementPassWordXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;".Replace("XXReplacementPassWordXX", Properties.Resources.SQLServerPassword);

Comment: interesting without "MultipleActiveRes‌​ultSets"   and using "datasource=SQLServer" instead of mysqlserver it would work. only Problem is an error then on the first usage: ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.